# How to make a specific HTML tag which does not appear in print command?

Tags: php, html

I am making a report sheet, in which there are several pages (fetched from DB entries). Now I am using:

```
<a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=1">Page 1</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=2">Page 2</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=3">Page 3</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=4">Page 4</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=5">Page 5</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=6">Page 6</a>
 <a href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=7">Page 7</a>
```

To link the rest of the report sheets, but whenever I give the print command the Page number as well as the `"href="getreport.php?id="` appears on the print screen.

Any possible ways to overcome this? Or any alternatives to switch to the next page?

Comment: What are you using as a printing screen? and can you explain your question some more?

Comment: Hi Mike, i just wanted to know, is there any possible way to eliminate an html tag or text on the screen to get printed on a paper after the users give the standard CTRL +P command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give css a common class to the elements which you want to hide in the print action. for example pls give a class called 'print-hide' to your elements like

```
<a class='print-hide' href="getreport.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&page=1">Page 1</a>
```

and use css @media print in your css file to hide the elements . for example

```
  @media print
  {
      .print-hide {
        displdisplay: none;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the href appearing, you will probably find that a style similar to this exists in your stylesheet inside the print media query.

```
a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")"
}
```

If this is the case and you wanted to get ride of it, simply delete it. Alternatively to overwrite it use:

```
@media print{
    a[href]:after {
        content: "";
    }
}
```